# adduser: Specify only one name in this mode

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I'm trying to add a user with this command:

```
#!/bin/bash

APPUSER="test1"
APPGROUP="test2"

# User
adduser -c 'uwsgi user' --group $APPGROUP --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --disabled-password $APPUSER
```

However it tells me I can only specify one name, but I am only specifying one name as far as I can see.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Does your script have DOS line endings? It might be interpreting a trailing carriage return in the value of `APPUSER` and/or at the end of the call to `adduser` as an additional user name. `bash` doesn't consider `\r` as whitespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

change --group to --gid

and find id by group name like this:

```
APPGROUP=`grep "test2" /etc/group|cut -d: -f3`

adduser -c 'uwsgi user' --gid $APPGROUP --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --disabled-password $APPUSER
```